# Python: 2d matrix initization using multiplication strange behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was working with some 2d data, where the data could be of different types. For ease of use, I opted for 2d lists.

Since the sizes were fixed, I tried to initialise a fixed 2d list using *multiplication*, like the code below:

```py
list2d = [[None] * size] * size
```

Now, when I try to populate any ***row, col*** in the list, all rows are just copies(reference) of a single 1d list. *(if that makes sense)*

**Sample code and output below:**

```py
list2d = [[None] * 4] * 4
for i in range(len(list2d)):
    list2d[i][i] = 42
print(list2d)
```

**Output:**

```
[[42, 42, 42, 42], [42, 42, 42, 42], [42, 42, 42, 42], [42, 42, 42, 42]]
```

So, my questions are thus:

- What is happening over here?
- Is each row a reference to a 1d list?
- What are some alternatives to declaring 2d list effectively?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that this question is duplicate :) but I tried to answer anyway, you can reseach more info later.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `[None] * size` inside `list2d = [[None] * size] * size` is created only once and reference is duplicated, so you have `size` times same structure created once by `[None] * size`.

I would suggest you to use [list comprehesion](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
list2d = [[None] * size] for _ range(size)]
```

That ensures that each `[None] * size]` will be created (and stored) as separated value.